# LeafletJS 1.6.0 map covers DIV that that works on 0.7.2

Tags: html, leaflet

I've created an overlay div on top of the LeafletJS map, sth like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class = "overlay">
        overlay text
    </div>
</div>
```

but for some reason it works with Leaflet 0.7.2 but don't for 1.6.0. The same code, the same CSS, different LeafletJS versions pulled in:

http://89.75.72.64:8080/div_test1.html - does not work, panel is seen only before the map tile is downloaded

http://89.75.72.64:8080/div_test2.html - works good

What's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

add to the overlay class a z-index:

```
.overlay{
  z-index: 1000;
}
```